# MS word automatization problem via windows service

Tags: windows, ms-word, windows-services, office-automation

In my project i'm using com msword library **(MSO.DLL**) for do something with word documents. In next code i can't getting document pointer from open method when i start my application as Windows Service. But it's working if i start as .exe app. Maybe somebody can provide idea what's wrong and what i can extra do, for solving this?
**P.S. my service starting as Administator user(but it's not helping).**

```
        _DocumentPtr spDoc = NULL;      
        auto filename = _variant_t(sTemplate); // example: "C:\Temp\example.doc"
        spDoc = spApp->Documents->Open(&filename, &vFalse, &vFalse); // RETURN NULL
        auto temp = spApp->Documents->Open(&filename, &vFalse, &vFalse).GetInterfacePtr();
        if(spDoc == nullptr)
        {
            auto error = GetLastError();
            LogEvent("GET LAST ERROR (%d)", error); /// RETURN 0
            LogEvent("GET temp (%s)", temp);  /// RETURN null
        }
```

Comment: What account are you using for the service ?

Comment: @RichardCritten i was created special other user in system as administator local account

Comment: Does the user profile exist?  That is on a default Windows installation on drive `C:` there should be a profile folder under `C:\Users` for the account you are using.  If not a lot of the assumptions for the user account eg registry hive, location of temporary folder etc will be incorrect.

Comment: @RichardCritten it's not related with users, as i think. Because another methods from WINAPI for files perfect work, and perfect undestand paths and filenames. I think it's a problem a ms word library in this context

Comment: What is your end goal of automating Word from a Windows service?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev it's a old approach from 200x)) I try to update solution to currently libraries condition. But some logic looks as deprecated and not supporting anymore((

Comment: Yes, consider using another approach of completing your tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i can't getting document pointer from open method when i start my application as Windows Service. But it's working if i start as .exe app.

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

If you deal with open XML documents you may consider using the Open XML SDK instead, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information. Otherwise, you may consider using third-party components designed for the server-side execution.

Comment: How many times have you posted this answer now? Can't you just close as duplicate?

Comment: How many times have people asked such questions? :) Every case may be different depending on the requirements.

Comment: This does not read like an answer tailored to the question, but copy-paste[d|able] boilerplate. But I don't care.

Comment: Yeah, but that is clear to the OP.